# Flutter Plugin Obfuscation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

We are preparing a flutter plug-in for a corporate company. We want users using this plugin not to see the codes. So how do we obfuscation the codes? I know you cannot upload it this way via pub.dev. We can send this plugin to them as an external file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with the current set of tools. I guess the main reason is that plugins are not compiled.

I also think it is this way by design. But you could always post a feature request to the Flutter team.

Comment: Actually I opened a issue from the flutter repository but they directed it here. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72471